# Q&A: How to test contracts under different accounts?

Tags: ethereum-classic

**This part of own Q&A serial of posts which shares knowledge gained during work on one project**

I was need to test my contract under different accounts and was looking for ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ether.js` allows to do this in this way:

```
 contract.connect(anotherUser).transfer();
```

Also I saw an option to create a separate contract which would act as Actor to verify test cases.

Answer (score 1):

In Hardhat case , u first need to get your hardhat blockchain simulated accounts using ethers.getSigners() function. Please know it returns an array with Signer Objects. When you have the accounts u can use the contract.connect method to connect your contract with the desired Signer Account u got from getSigners() function.

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-ethers
https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/

```
let [account1,account2,account3] = await ethers.getSigners();
await contract.connect(account2).method();
```